# DIV with higher z-index hides on clicking on div with lower z index containing Silverlight object

Tags: html, css, silverlight-5.0, window-resize

I have 2 divs inside a form and I want one div to be always floating above other. The div with id "help" displays a help button. When I navigate to the page, the help div is on top of the second div but if I click anywhere on the second div the first div hides. if I resize the window it appears again.

NOTE: the second div expands to full width and height of the parent.

```
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%; display:flex; flex-
    flow:column; ">
    <div id="help" style="position:absolute; z-index:1;">
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:0;">
      <!-- Here there is a Silverlight component -->
    </div>
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: div help actually has a Zendesk script that takes care of the help button.The other div contains a silverlight application.

Comment: So, probably the problem is by silverlight, try to use google to search issues with silverlight and z-index or silverlight and problems with resize, I think your problem is not html or css, is for 3rd party elements that use SO api implemented by the browser as Silverlight is

Comment: Thank you.. it was in fact Silverlight. Setting the "Windowless" property to true for the silverlight object fixed it. I'll explain more in the answer below.

Comment: Great, also make an edit to question and title to refer to silverlight, probably it will be helpfull to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was setting "Windowless" to true in silverlight object.

```
 <param value="true" name="windowless"/>
```

According to microsoft documentationin windowless mode, the Silverlight plug-in does not have its own rendering window. Instead, the plug-in content is displayed directly by the browser window. This enables Silverlight content to visually overlap and blend with HTML content.

https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc838156(v=vs.95).aspx